# Style search results (text) like a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have searched on internet about styling a search result of an input field but there is not that much... or it might just be me not being very good at this... ;) So my question is how can I style a search result of an input field like a dropdown menu ? If it can be useful, I made an ajax live search so that's why I want to style the outputs. An early thank you !(Hope I was clear enough :) )

Here is my html :

```
<body>
    <h1>LIVE SEARCH WITH AJAX TEST</h1>
    <div class="search">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="recherche" class="search">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="resultat" id="resultat">
        <a href="#">Search Result #1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #2</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #3</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #4</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You want to make Search Box with Suggestions Dropdown ?

Comment: @Friend yes like google but style it by myself

Answer (score 0):

You can style it with css with selectors just like any html element. Here is a [quick guide](https://blog.udemy.com/search-box-css/) it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but that is just styling the search box, do you have the same for the results once you typed in the search box ?

Comment: @keyup38 Do you have a copy of the code? The results that are generated are an <li> that you can style in your main css file, so you can use an id to change those elements or add classes via javascript.